# Is my method safe?

Tags: java, security, jwt, simple-web-token

I am creating for our web application a tokensystem. What do you guys think, if is this `isWebTokenAvailable()` Method safe?

```
/**
     * Checked if webToken is available {@link de.security.WebToken}.
     *
     * @param webToken to check if webToken is available.
     * @return true if webToken is available and if there is no available token then returns false.
     */
    public boolean isWebTokenAvailable(@NonNull String webToken) {
        return !em.createNamedQuery("validateToken").setParameter("token", webToken)
                .getResultList().isEmpty();
    }
```

Comment: which safety are you talking about?

Comment: @ShanuGupta for example, what if I give another token String. It can be wrong but my list is not empty, thats why I can true as return.

Comment: What does the `validateToken` query look like.

Comment: What kind of security you are talking about here, related to sql injection in the query or authentication on the basis of your token?

Comment: @Kayaman `@NamedQuery(name = "validateToken", query = "select t from WebToken t where t.token = :token and t.expireDate > current_timestamp() ")`

Comment: @sCom my concern is authentication on the basis of my token

Comment: Your code has no concept of a **wrong** token. There are just tokens which are either valid (or available) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have understood,if you have authentication concerns, you just need to verify the below steps:

- While you are creating a token you need to set basic things in it
  like userRole/id according to the requirment of you app.
- And you  need to validate the user by extracting that info from the token and
  validating it with the info in your database.
- Providing token from
  the db is just the step you are doing after authentication, that just
  checks the expiry.